# How can I issue carriage returns after a system call in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, system

Context: In a large program built mostly in MATLAB, I am calling a program to display some information to the user, like so:

```
batchCommand = ['"', programPath, '" ', '"', inputPath, '"'];
system(batchCommand);
```

Here's the issue: the program at `programPath` opens two consecutive splash screens, which require the user to press enter in order to bypass. That really busts up the flow of my program, and I'd like to do away with it. There is no option to run the program without the splash screens. The splash screens are in-focus, so pressing return clears them with no further input. So, I'd like to have MATLAB issue a couple of carriage returns for me.

Here's the catch: the `system` command halts execution of MATLAB code until the opened program is closed. I need to work around this in some way to get those returns issued.

I've tried working with `-echo`, to no avail.

Has anyone out there done this, or know how to?

Comment: Maybe something like AutoHotKey can work for you.

Comment: @Yvon, Afraid not. This program is going to be distributed, and that would be a pretty inelegant solution. Still, I'd never heard of AutoHotKey, and it looks like it might be useful for other things. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: First of all, if you're distributing your program which contains something you cannot handle, you should try to contact with the person/party who has developed that piece of software. AutoHotKey is one of general-purpose automated script builders. It simulates mouse/keyboard input and has a lot of (Windows) operating system-based instructions, such like 'find window' and 'wait for dialog box to appear'. You can build a separate program that handle the splash screens.

Comment: Or you can call system API (such as Windows DLL libraries) in your own C program, which will then be called by Matlab. An idea pointed out in https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/165663

Comment: Trust me, I have. Not an option. Unfortunately, I'm also very restricted on exactly what I can distribute. That said, an API call through C may do the trick... I'll look into it. Thanks!